# How does this object still have its properties set during / after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following JS method:

```
function LoadSearch(fromWhere, fieldCount) 
{
    try 
    {
        var icdCodes = {};
        // set a bunch of properties
        icdCodes.IsSuggested = false;

        if (fromWhere == 'MI-Suggested')
        {
            icdCodes.IsSuggested = true;
            icdCodes.FromWhere += "-" + $("#cmbSomeControl_Tab3").val();
        }

        //asynchronus call for open popup
        AjaxRequest(icdCodes, 'html', 'post', '/SomeController/SomeMethod', 'application/json;',
        function (response)
        {
            if (icdCodes.IsSuggested == true)
                $("#txtCode").val('beep');
        }
        , function (error) { Error(error); });
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        logError(err, arguments.callee.trace());
    }
}
```

It's pretty simple; all it does is set a few properties on this `icdCodes` object, the ajax gets the view, then during ht eresponse I just set a value in a textbox.

**Question**: `icdCodes` only exists within the scope of this method, yet if I set a breakpoint on the first line where the variable is declared it does **not** get triggered during the response when `txtCode` gets the value `beep` assigned. How does this variable maintain its values throughout the process?

The method that returns the view performs the following:

```
return View(base.GetViewPath("Codes"), objCodes);
```

But the `response` object does not contain the values in `objCodes` (which stores the values assigned to `icdCodes` in the JS)

It is my understanding that the order of operations works like so:

- `LoadSearch` is called
- `icdCodes` is created and assigned its values
- The Ajax call is made to get the view
- The Javascript continues to run, this method completes and `icdCodes` goes out of scope
- The server finishes returning the view, which is "caught" by the javascript and it executes the code defined in `function(response) { ... }`;

If that is correct, then how is `IsSuggested` still true? If that is not correct, then what's happening?

I read the wiki article about [XML HTTP Requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) as well as a few other resources on ajax but I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: @charlietfl If I set one in the response it does get picked up. But what you're saying is is that all the other code, which sets `icdCodes` properties, is still being run a second time? So when it evaluates it's still the same as what I would expect prior to the AJAX call?

Comment: yes...is still in scope of main function when in the response

Comment: @charlietfl JavaScript is not multithreaded, so that's not quite correct...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan right am aware is single threaded but trying to say that breakpoint isn't being seen inside response due to asychnronoucity. No sure how to phrase it

Comment: @charlietfl Well, if you can find the words / explanation and post it as an answer I'll happily Accept it.